# How to convert iso 8859-1 in simple letter using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, iso-8859-1

I m trying to clean my sqlite database using python. At first I loaded using this code:
import sqlite3, pandas as pd
con = sqlite3.connect("DATABASE.db")

```
import sqlite3, pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT TITLE from DOCUMENT", con)
```

So I got the dirty words. for example this "Conciliaci\363n" I want to get "Conciliacion". I used this code:

```
df['TITLE']=df['TITle'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8'))
```

I got b'' in blank cells. and got 'Conciliaci\\363n' too. So maybe I'm doing wrong. how can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `str("Conciliaci\363n")` give you `"Conciliación"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear, but if your string contains a literal backslash and numbers like this:

```py
>>> s= r"Conciliaci\363n"  # A raw string to make a literal escape code
>>> s
'Conciliaci\\363n'         # debug display of string shows an escaped backslash
>>> print(s)
Conciliaci\363n            # printing prints the escape
```

Then this will decode it correctly:

```py
>>> s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')  # convert to byte string, then decode
'Conciliación'
```

If you want to lose the accent mark as your question shows, then decomposing the Unicode string, converting to ASCII ignoring errors, then converting back to a Unicode string will do it:

```py
>>> s2 = s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
>>> s2
'Conciliación'
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.normalize('NFD',s2) # Make Unicode decomposed form
'Conciliación'              # The ó is now an ASCII 'o' and a combining accent
>>> ud.normalize('NFD',s2).encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('ascii')
'Conciliacion'   # accent isn't ASCII, so is removed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark Tolonen for your help. It worked.